# Kotlin/Native - cinterop on windows

Tags: c, compiler-errors, kotlin, interop, kotlin-native

I wanted o experiment with cinterop on windows. But so far I only found tutorials for using kotlin native with mac. So, does someone know where to find a tutorial for using kotlin native on windows?

For example I'm struggling finding the default directory, where the c libraries are located. And if just give the path to a library for cinterop, I always get an error that the file is not win32 executable.

Has someone similar experiences with that?

Answer (score 1):

cinterop shall work on Windows same way as on other host platforms. Please specify command line that gave you problems. To find include directories -complierOpts -I shall do, see, for example, https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/8aa4acee8844aae7a84af89b783c73ce6f20de92/samples/tetris/build.bat#L13